# JavaScript - duplicating array doesn't work

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am tring to make an array with duplicate elements. For example:

```
var myArray = ["one", "two", "five"];
```

when I'm looping through the for loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
  myArray.push(myArray[i]);
}
```

my browser crashes! I don't get any meaningful error. Could someone explain why is this happening?

Comment: Every call to `.push()` increases `myArray.length` by 1.

Comment: Thanks a lot I've solved it using concat, but I wanted to understand why does it happen :)

Answer (score 7):

Your `for` loop never ends, because the length is increasing for every iteration.

For getting only one copy, you could store the length in advance and loop only this length.

```js
var myArray = ["one", "two", "five"];

for (var i = 0, l = myArray.length; i < l; i++){
    myArray.push(myArray[i]);
}

console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 6):

When you use add items to the array, the length grows, which makes the for loop add more items, which increase the length, and so on...

A simple solution is to [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) the array to itself:

```js
var myArray = ["one", "two", "five"];

var result = myArray.concat(myArray);

console.log(result);
```

Or push all the items at once using spread, if you want to mutate the array:

```js
var myArray = ["one", "two", "five"];

myArray.push(...myArray);

console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you change myArray.length to a constant number, this problem does not happen. However, the reason for the crashing is every call to .push() increases  your array length by 1
anyway, I think this crash is interesting and could be an unhandled bug maybe!

```html
var myArray = ["one", "two", "five"];
var l=myArray.length;
for(var i = 0; i < l; i++){// for example l=3 here
  myArray.push(myArray[i]);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

An ES6 solution would be use the spread operator. Which behaves like a concat.

```
let myArray = ["one" ,"two","five"];
myArray = [ ...myArray, ...myArray];
```